# Did Tasha Lem teach River how to fly the Tardis?

Tags: doctor-who

In Series 5 Episode 4, Amy asks River:

> Amy: How come you can fly the TARDIS?
>
> River: Oh, I had lessons from the very best.
>
> The Doctor: [flattered] Well...yeah.
>
> River: It's a shame you were busy that day.

Could Tasha be the one who taught River how to fly the Tardis? I hope she returns.

Comment: So many question about Tasha - River lately... I just don't see the connection. Yeah, I've seen the fan theories and none of them ring true to me. With the amount of "people" in the Doctor Whoniverse, why do these two have to be linked? Is it just 50th Anniversary fever? I don't get it. Did River break out of jail (again) for TARDIS lessons (without a TARDIS)? When would this have happened?

Comment: It's mostly because there seems to be connection between Tasha and The Doctor..... It was also implied that The Tardis itself taught River.

Answer (score 7):

### We have no evidence for this.

Banter between River and the Doctor shouldn't be taken at face value, and we don't know anything about whether Tasha and River ever met at all.

Also, River at one point claimed the TARDIS itself taught her how to fly it.

Answer (score 6):

This is explained in the episode *Let's kill hitler*. River learns flying the TARDIS from the TARDIS herself. River says

> (It materialises around Amy and Rory.) 
>   *AMY:* Doctor? Doctor, you did it. He did it! (River steps out from behind the console.) 
>   *RIVER:* **I seem to be able to fly her. She showed me how. She taught me.** The
>   Doctor says I'm the child of the Tardis. What does he mean? 
>   *AMY:* Where is he?

Comment: It's a shame that Tasha couldn't be the Tardis herself :-) I loved that episode. The connection between the two was brilliant.

Comment: Are you referring to _The Doctor's wife_ ?

Answer (score 2):

No, River as a 'child of the TARDIS' just knows how to pilot it (*Let's Kill Hitler*).

Or, the Doctor taught her (*The Pandorica Opens*).  Or, someone besides the Doctor taught her (your quote from *The Time of the Angels*).

Since we literally see her pilot it without instruction in *Let's Kill Hitler*, chances are, that's the true one.